# Groovy @Builder compile error

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to take advantage of @Builder fluent API within JAVA class. However I came across a scenario which can't crack:

This is a **HALResource.groovy**:

```
import groovy.transform.builder.Builder
import groovy.transform.builder.SimpleStrategy
import org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport

@Builder(builderStrategy = SimpleStrategy, prefix = '')
class HALResource extends ResourceSupport {
    String name
}
```

and this is execution logic in **Java.java**

```
public class Java {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new HALResource().name("Bug"));
    }
}
```

When I try to compile:

```
        System.out.println(new HALResource().name("Bug"));
                                            ^
  symbol:   method name(String)
  location: class HALResource
  1 error
```

However I comment the println statement and then compile the project everything is fine and compiled **HALResource.class** has the fluent API generated:

```
public HALResource name(String name) {
    CallSite[] var2 = $getCallSiteArray();
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}
```

I am using gradle wrapper 2.13 + JDK9U60
Is this a bug/configuration problem or have I missed something in the documentation?

Comment: Do you have your Java in `src/main/groovy`? Gradle compiles the Java first, then the groovy. So when the Java is compiled, the groovy class hasn't been generated. Moving your Java files into the groovy sourceset should help

Comment: @tim_yates - yes they are in src/main/groovy.

Comment: This appears to be a compilation issue re: order, classpath, etc. I was able to work around it by using separate Gradle projects. If this is of interest, I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelEaster Colleague explained that this is indeed compilation issue as the compiler first generates class stubs to fulfill dependency contracts but since bytecode transformations happens later the contract is broken right of the bat. A clean solution is to move such beans to another module (make it a dependency), this way compiler will generate all of the bytecode with all transformations before hand. Other solutions were not very clean. Thank you for support thou.